# If f is everywhere finite (positive) and μ (ν) is σ-finite, then ν (μ) is σ-finite.

Tags: measure-theory

Let $(X, M, μ)$ be a measure space, and let $f$ be a nonnegative, measurable function. Define the measure $ν(E)=\int_E f dμ$.

(a) Show that if $f$ is everywhere finite and $μ$ is $σ$-finite then $ν$ is
σ-finite.

(b) Show that if $f$ is everywhere positive and $ν$ is $σ$-finite then $μ$
is $σ$-finite.

I have no idea how to solve this. Radon–Nikodym Theorem hasn't been discussed yet, but even so any relevant theorem on the web is about assuming both $μ$ and $ν$, $σ$-finite or at least one of them so. They don't conclude one from the other based on how $f$ is. Can someone please help me out?

Comment: HINT: note that $X=\bigcup_{k\in \mathbb N }f^{-1}([k,k+1))$

Comment: @L.G. I have posted a detailed answer. Please let me know if you have any questions regardin the answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Item (a)**. Since $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, there is $\{E_n\}_n$ such that $X=\bigcup_n E_n$ and $\mu(E_n) < \infty $, for all $n$.

Let $[f < m] = \{x\in X : f(x) <m\}$.  It follows immediately that :

1. For each $n$ and $m$, $\nu(E_n \cap [f < m]) \leq m\mu(E_n) <  \infty $
2. $X=\bigcup_{n, m} (E_n\cap [f < m])$ (because $f$ is everywhere finite)

Since $\{ E_n \cap [f < m]\}_{n,m}$ is a countable collection of subsets of $X$, we have that $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

**Item (b)** Since $\nu$ is $\sigma$-finite, there is $\{F_n\}_n$ such that $X=\bigcup_n F_n$ and $\nu(F_n) < \infty $, for all $n$.

Let $[f > 1/m] = \{x\in X : f(x) > 1/m\}$. Then we have, for each $n$ and $m$,
$$ \frac{1}{m} \mu(F_n \cap [f > 1/m]) \leq \nu(F_n \cap [f > 1/m]) \leq \nu(F_n) < \infty $$
So, for all $n$ and $m$, $\mu(F_n \cap [f > 1/m])< \infty$.
Since $f$ is everywhere positive, we have that
$$X=\bigcup_{n, m} (F_n\cap [f > 1/ m])$$

Since $\{ F_n \cap [f > 1/m]\}_{n,m}$ is a countable collection of subsets of $X$, we have that $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: ♡♡♡ THANK YOU ♡♡♡